# R editing global object defined in parent environment

Tags: r

I want to edit the data frame dat defined in the parent function just as in the example, but the output (return from main) gives a data frame where the edits has not occured. It is obviously due to a misuse of global variables in R, but could someone explain please why this is and how I can make it happen?

```
indat <- data.frame(a = '0', b = '0')


main <-function(data){
  assign("dat", data, envir = .GlobalEnv) 
      inner1()
      inner2()
  return(dat)      
}


inner1<-function(){
  print(dat$a)
  dat$a <- '1'
  return()

}

inner2<-function(){
  print(dat$b)
  dat$b <- '1'
  return() 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
dat$a <- '1'
```

to

```
dat$a <<- '1'
```

The <<- assigns values to the global environment, <- operates on the local, 'inner-function' environment. 
Although you've created 'data' as a global variable, R creates a new 'data'-variable in the inner1()-environment when using the '<-' operator as I understand it.